# Associate primarycontactid to Case-Dynamics CRM web API

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-webapi

I am trying to create a case and associate a contact in the primarycontactId field. I am using an alternate key to look up the contact as below.

```
POST https://xxxxx.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v8.2/incidents HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
OData-MaxVersion: 4.0
OData-Version: 4.0
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Host: xxxxxx.crm.dynamics.com
Content-Length: 161

{
  "title": "case101",
  "primarycontactid@odata.bind": "https://xxxxx.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v8.2/contacts(xxi_xxx='2533274975913147')"
}
```

Code as below

```
using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                var method2 = new HttpMethod("POST");
                Uri requesturi = new Uri(string.Format("{0}/api/data/v8.2/", url));
                httpClient.BaseAddress = requesturi;
                httpClient.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 4);  // 10 minutes
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                result = GetS2SAccessToken(url, pwd);
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result);
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("OData-Version", "4.0");
                HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(method,string.Format( "contacts(xxxxx_xxxx='{0}')",xxxx.ToString()));
                request.Content = new StringContent(props.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                HttpRequestMessage request2 = new HttpRequestMessage(method2, string.Format("incidents"));
                request2.Content = new StringContent(props1.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

                HttpResponseMessage createResponse1;
                createResponse1 = await httpClient.SendAsync(request2);
                return createResponse1.Content;
         }
```

However I get:

> An unexpected error occurred.","innererror":{
>         "message":"An unexpected error occurred.","type":"System.ServiceModel.FaultException.","type":"System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault, Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.OData.CrmODataServiceDataProvider.CreateEdmEntity(CrmODataExecutionContext context, String edmEntityName, EdmEntityObject entityObject, Boolean isUpsert)\r\n   at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]","stacktrace":"   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.OrganizationSdkServiceInternal.Create(Entity entity, CorrelationToken correlationToken, CallerOriginToken callerOriginToken, WebServiceType serviceType, Boolean checkAdminMode, Dictionary`2 optionalParameters)\r\n   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.OData.CrmODataExecutionContext.Create(Entity entity)\r\n   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.OData.EntityController.PostEntitySet(String entitySetName, EdmEntityObject entityObject)\r\

Has anyone experienced this before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mixed up. Verify this & correct the schema name.

Incident has 2 optional contact lookups & schema name is primarycontactid & responsiblecontactid.

```
primarycontactid@odata.bind
```

But Incident has a **mandatory** Customer lookup & schema name is `customerid`. Without this Incident cannot be created. Pass this, request will succeed.

```
customerid_contact@odata.bind
```

Comment: I get the below error when I use customerIderror":{
    "code":"","message":"An undeclared property 'customerid' which only has property annotations in the payload but no property value was found in the payload. In OData, only declared navigation properties and declared named streams can be represented as properties without values.","innererror":{
      "message":"An undeclared property 'customerid' which only has property annotations in the payload but no p

Comment: Any suggestion on how I pass this in with a Jobject as in my code? Appreciate the help!

Comment: Try to build the request using CRM Rest builder

Comment: https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/crmtipsfromadeveloper/archive/2017/06/21/know-how-set-a-lookup-value-on-create-update-of-a-record-using-mscrm-webapi-an-undeclared-property-error

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if the Web API allows populating a lookup field via an alternate key.

This two step process should work...

1. Retrieve the Contact's GUID by its alternate key
2. Populate the lookup using the ID rather than the alternate key, i.e.:

`"primarycontactid@odata.bind": "/contacts(F56D5D25-8B0D-E711-8104-00155D6FD705)"`

Comment: I tried using GUID too for a contactid, seemed to get the same error

Comment: I am doing this using C#, creating a JObject(props1) to string and passing in with a HTTP request.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this in the request body, It will help.

```
"primarycontactid@odata.bind":"/contacts(alternate_key_field='2222222')"
```