# How to POST data in Dynamics 365 using HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, .net-core, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I have requirement to read data from Dynamics 365 online and to write data as well.

Since my application Target Framework is .Net Core 2.1 so I am unable to use Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk and decided to use Web api instead.

In my code I am using HttpWebRequest with "GET" and "POST" methods, the GET operation works fine and am able to retrieve records from D365 using web api.
When I use the POST operation the code executes properly without any error but when I navigate to D365 entity I do not see any newly created record.

Below is my code

The `GetContactDetailsAsync` function works fine and returns result but the `CreateCaseAsync` function is not working

```
public static async Task<string> GetContactDetailsAsync()
{
 string organizationUrl = "https://xxxxx.crmX.dynamics.com";
 string clientId = "xxxxxxxx-73aa-xxxx-94cc-8dc7941f6600";
 string appKey = "Xxxx81H/7TUFErt5C/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx=";
 string aadInstance = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/";
 string tenantID = "xxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com";

        try
        {
            ClientCredential clientcred = new ClientCredential(clientId, appKey);
            AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(aadInstance + tenantID);

            AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(organizationUrl, clientcred);
            var requestedToken = authenticationResult.AccessToken;

            var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri("https://xxxxxxxxxx.api.crmx.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.1/contacts()?$select=fullname,contactid,emailaddress1&$filter=mobilephone eq '"+History.userMobile+"'"));
            webRequest.KeepAlive = false;
            webRequest.ServicePoint.ConnectionLimit = 1;

            webRequest.Method = "GET";
            webRequest.ContentLength = 0;
            webRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", String.Format("Bearer {0}", requestedToken));
            webRequest.Headers.Add("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
            webRequest.Headers.Add("OData-Version", "4.0");
            webRequest.Accept = "application/json";
            webRequest.ContentType = "application/json";

            //if contact with user provided phone number found, ask for problem description
            try
            {
                using (var response1 = webRequest.GetResponse() as System.Net.HttpWebResponse)
                {
                    using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(response1.GetResponseStream()))
                    {
                        var response = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                History.isUserFound = false;
                string error = ex.Message;
                return "Sorry, I found that you are not using any of our services...";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { return ex.ToString(); }

    }




public static async void CreateCaseAsync()
        {
 string organizationUrl = "https://xxxxx.crmX.dynamics.com";
 string clientId = "xxxxxxxx-73aa-xxxx-94cc-8dc7941f6600";
 string appKey = "Xxxx81H/7TUFErt5C/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx=";
 string aadInstance = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/";
 string tenantID = "xxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com";

        //trying to establish connection with D365 here
        try
        {
            ClientCredential clientcred = new ClientCredential(clientId, appKey);
            AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(aadInstance + tenantID);

            AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(organizationUrl, clientcred);
            var requestedToken = authenticationResult.AccessToken;

            var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri("https://xxxxxxxx.api.crmx.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.1/incidents"));
            webRequest.KeepAlive = false;
            webRequest.ServicePoint.ConnectionLimit = 1;

            webRequest.Method = "POST";
            webRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", String.Format("Bearer {0}", requestedToken));
            webRequest.Headers.Add("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
            webRequest.Headers.Add("OData-Version", "4.0");
            webRequest.Accept = "application/json";
            webRequest.ContentType = "application/json";

            string json = "{\"title\":\"title by chat bot\"}";
            byte[] byteArray;
            byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
            webRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

            try
            {
                Stream requestDataStream = await webRequest.GetRequestStreamAsync();
                requestDataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
                requestDataStream.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { }
        }

        catch (Exception ex) { }

    }
```

I have tried changing 
`string json = "{\"title\":\"title by chat bot\"}"` to
`"{'title':'title by chat bot'}"` and `"{title:title by chat bot}"` as well.

Also I have tried changing
`Stream requestDataStream = await webRequest.GetRequestStreamAsync();` to
`Stream requestDataStream = webRequest.GetRequestStream();` as well
but nothing worked.

Unable to figure out what I am missing in my code. Any help is highly appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

Actually code looks fine but you should get 400 Bad request exception. Because the json is missing `customerid` and the [basic payload for creating incident](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51727311/7920473) should be like below:

```
{
  "title": "title by chat bot",
  "customerid_account@odata.bind": "/accounts(f686f062-e542-e811-a955-000d3ab27a43)"
}
```

You can refer this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45364479/7920473) for clarity.

Comment: Hi Arun, I understand that customerid on incident entity is required so I've tried the same code for contact entity with this json - {
  "fristname": "bot",
  "lastname": "framework"
}   in contact entity only lastname field is required, but still it did not worked

Comment: @Dev check that firstname typo. Try using CRM REST Builder to build queries & payloads, you can test there itself..

Comment: @Dev was it helpful?

Answer (score -1):

Here is the Code for Webapi using Javascript. I just tried below code in my Org and it worked for me.

```
var entity = {};
entity.title = "CCCCAAAASSSEEEE";

var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("PATCH", Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl() + "/api/data/v9.1/incidents(BA8BC3CD-D94F-E911-A82F-000D3A385A1C)", true);
req.setRequestHeader("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
req.setRequestHeader("OData-Version", "4.0");
req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
req.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState === 4) {
        req.onreadystatechange = null;
        if (this.status === 204) {
            //Success - No Return Data - Do Something
        } else {
            Xrm.Utility.alertDialog(this.statusText);
        }
    }
};
req.send(JSON.stringify(entity));
```

and Below is the link where you could find exactly how to use PATCH method for CRM using c#

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/webapi/web-api-functions-actions-sample-csharp